# Does App Store Updater Download Always All Content?

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store

I've developed an iPhone/iPad application which is 100 Mb.
It contains images and static libraries.

Does app store is so smart, so when users download new version of application updater will download only changed files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**App Store Updates:**

When an App is updated, the previous version is completely removed from the device, and the updated version is installed in its place.  *HOWEVER*, all the files in: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);` and all the key/value's in `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` persist through the update.

---

**iOS Updates:**

[Updates will now only contain the changes - Announced at the 2011 WWDC](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/)

Some more articles reporting on it:
[apple-shows-ios-5-with-new-notification-system-delta-updates-twitter-integration-and-much-more](http://www.yourdailymac.net/2011/06/apple-shows-ios-5-with-new-notification-system-delta-updates-twitter-integration-and-much-more/)
[ios-5-supports-ota-delta-software-updates](http://www.limera1n.cc/2011/06/ios-5-supports-ota-delta-software_25.html)
[ios-5-over-the-air-update](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/07/22/ios-5-over-the-air-update-video-documents-on-icloud-and-other-notes/)
[beta-4-of-ios-5-released-by-apple-over-the-air](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2011/07/22/beta-4-of-ios-5-released-by-apple-over-the-air/)
[ota-everything](http://brooksreview.net/2011/10/ota-everything/)
[ios-5-to-allow-some-ota-updates-through-3g](http://pocketnow.com/iphone/ios-5-to-allow-some-ota-updates-through-3g)

Comment: No, this used to be the case but iOS 5 actually does delta updates.

Comment: Huh? This is only for iOS updates not third party apps AFAIK?

Comment: That's what I had originally thought also, @Rog.  I did some more digging and it does appear that the OTA delta's are only for `iOS` version updates and `App Store Updates` still work the same.